# Close reasons cheat sheet

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Shog9 commented on [his answer explaining the new close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215546/13295), when asked for more clarity:

> I will answer a separate question on this topic with a mapping of specific examples of questions to close reasons though. After I eat breakfast. If someone asks one.

So here is that question.

I noticed that the "minimal understanding" close reason is [gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/). Skimming through the discussion there, it seems like there's some confusion about how the various close reasons should be used (at least, it was confusing to me, because I always thought of "minimal understanding" as being similar to "too localized," but it seems to have been rolled into "too broad" now).

Can we make some kind of an easy-to-reference cheat sheet **for each close reason with examples**?

Something like this, maybe:

---

- **unclear what you're asking**

  NARQ.

  Examples: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031130/allow-space-into-my-regex), ...
- **too broad**

  canhazcodez / homework.

  Examples: ...
- **primarily opinion-based**

  shark v gorilla.

  Examples: ...
- **general computing**

  configuring a server or network.

  Examples: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933539), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902145), ...
- **can't be reproduced**

  too localized / typo / given code does not produce given error.

  Examples: ...
- **off-site resource**

  "is there a library" / "which editor" / "where are the docs."

  Examples: ...

---

And just to clarify, "minimal understanding" been rolled into "too broad," correct?

Comment: homework is too broad? sounds like you want a mapping from what you object to and what you're going to say it is in order to close it anyway

Comment: The whole reason for the change was that people were making broad generalizations like this instead of actually thinking about what the close reason is stating and whether or not it applies to the question at hand.

Comment: Shark. No contest.

Comment: @itsbruce [citation needed] ;)

Comment: @KateGregory I want a mapping from what these things say to how they're generally intended to be used.

Comment: @TheCommunity There is no mapping.  What they say is exactly how they're intended to be used.  If you're using a reason to close something that the reason doesn't actually state, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: __Do people here even understand that Shog9 said specifically for someone to ask this question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding/215546#comment696337_215546__.  Personally, I'd like to see Shog9's answer.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I guess not.

Comment: @Servy, what are you talking about, a lot of the reasons are very Unclear now, as many people have stated.

Comment: @TheCommunity, maybe you should reference that request.

Comment: @LanceRoberts honestly I expected this kind of response but just figured I'd make a good fall guy since I don't participate much here anyway. Feel free to edit the Q if you want though

Comment: @LanceRoberts That comment is specifically saying *not* to do this.  It's shog *specifically* saying that he's annoyed at people making mappings like is shown in the question here.  `"I'm tired of getting burned by folks taking pithy terms for questions and applying them in cases where they don't remotely apply"`  That comment is *only* talking about providing some good canonical *examples of questions* of each close reason.

Comment: @Servy, Here's the quote, emphasis mine: " I will answer a separate question on this topic with a mapping of specific examples of questions to close reasons though. After I eat breakfast. __If someone asks one.__"

Comment: @LanceRoberts Yep.  I saw that.  That's not what this is though.  This is asking to map close reasons to pithy terms for questions, the specific thing that shog was complaining about.

Comment: @Servy, quoting the OP now: "Can we make some kind of an easy-to-reference cheat sheet for each close reason __with examples__?"

Comment: Question edited to make the source clear.

Comment: @LanceRoberts So you've just ignored the use of the pithy terms for questions here, or do they just not matter?  If it were *just* asking for examples then it would be asking what that comment corresponds to.  But it's not, it's asking for that *in addition to encouraging the exact problem this change is trying to address*.  It's that second part that's a problem.

Comment: @Servy to my understanding the new close reasons were essentially the old close reasons, reworded to be less offensive to the OP, but still having roughly the same intended use. See "every close has its thorn." Why not map the concise old close reasons to the fluffy new ones where applicable?

Comment: @TheCommunity Because the close reasons aren't always being used correctly.  The categories *don't* map 1:1, and assuming that they do has lead to incorrect close reasons, hence the further changes.  Take a look through the post that is linked in your own question (from Lance's edit).  It's explaining in depth some of the problems with this exact mentality.

Comment: @Servy I did take a look at it. I still think a cheat sheet would be nice. A cheat sheet isn't supposed to be an exhaustive reference, it's just a quick lookup table to remind us which ones we're supposed to use for common cases.

Comment: @TheCommunity And you read Shog's comments (which I've quoted in comments here) about the problems with doing *exactly* what you're proposing, including further explanations of some of the specific problems that this behavior causes and why he is working so hard to avoid this mentality?

Comment: @Servy, yes. I don't intend to "apply them in cases where they don't remotely apply."

Comment: @TheCommunity It wasn't purely just a rewording to make the OP feel better, it was also about getting people to stop closing questions that didn't show effort.  That's what downvotes are for, not closing, yet people were abusing Too Localized and Minimal Understanding for low effort questions.  You can kind of see how the recent changes evolved from the [discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort).

Comment: @Troyen as far as I can tell, when [this was proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497), it was purely about fluffing up the language and nothing else. I have asked low effort questions because I didn't feel like finding a windows box to test something on or whatever, but never had any "minimal understanding" close votes, presumably because it was clear that I understood what I was doing. How many questions can you find that show *understanding* but no *effort* that have been closed with "minimal understanding?"

Answer (score 15):

Here is an attempt at a flow chart [discussed in chat here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/shog-jan-jmac-discuss-closing-all-the-stuff):

[image]

Comment: "Has it been answered here before?" if *No* then why do we close it as duplicate?

Comment: @hims, where would you get such a silly notion like that? I would never ever suggest such a thing. Unless it took more than 5 minutes to fix and was therefore outside the edit grace period. And then only if someone checked the revision history. (nice catch)

Comment: "Is it about programming -> no -> off-topic" is misleading, I think. At least half of the OT sub-reasons could apply to things that are about programming. So if it's not about programming, it's OT, but if it is about programming, it still might be OT. What I'm trying to figure out is if the stuff that was OT before is still OT, and we need to use a different close reason, or if some of it is no longer OT now that the close reasons are gone.

Comment: @TheCommunity, the subreasons are 'about hardware' 'about servers' 'was just a typo' (which may be about programming, but is an outlier reason in general), or 'a recommendation' -- so I think if it's about programming, it's generally speaking not going to be closed as off-topic unless it's a custom reason

Comment: So you think there are more write-ins than "typo" and "recommendation" combined? Or you don't think "recommendation" questions can be about programming? What about the old OT sub-reasons that didn't disclude stuff about programming, like "minimal understanding?" I don't have any stats handy but I have a feeling that plenty of OT closures have been about programming.

Comment: @TheCommunity, yeah, many off-topic closed questions were about programming -- and that was part of the issue and the reason for the change as I understand it. I just think that this mimics what my understanding of the close flow that Shog is talking about, not that it is what the community necessarily agrees with. I think closing bad questions as off-topic even though they are on the topic of the site and not closeable for other reasons doesn't make much sense, but I'm just one person so feel free to disagree.

Comment: I guess this is where the confusion comes from. If someone in an authoritative position were to say "stuff like this was off-topic before, but now it's not," it would all be perfectly clear and there would be no question. Instead there was kind of the implication that topicness hadn't really changed and that some close reasons had just been rolled together because they were too vague to be useful to the asker (but not necessarily because they no longer applied). What would be nice would be a clear answer as to whether topicness has changed.

Comment: You may be interested in [Shouldn't "off topic" be only about...off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086), @TheCommunity.

Comment: @Josh, thanks! Already read it before, but a good re-read. And good food for thought. I'm currently doing a bit of work thinking about our 'off-topic' close reasons on [workplace.se], so this is great timing for me to have looked at that again. Making it clear to users is always a good thing.

Answer (score 8):

I'll give you examples. I'll talk about the problems in those examples. But I won't classify them beyond the close reason itself: doing so leads to something akin to a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) - multiple distinct problems getting lumped into common category, with unhelpful results. Worse, it implies that you can skip identifying a problem entirely, and apply close reasons based purely on a superficial examination of a question - while this *is* often feasible, doing so in every case leads to cases where useful questions are closed based on irrelevant factors rather than the presence of actual problems on the site.

### duplicate of

This is fairly obvious: a question asks for a solution to the same problem as a different question.

#### Example:

[A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000922/writefile-hangs-when-usb-cable-disconnected) is a duplicate of [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835881/releasing-a-unplugged-virtual-serial-port)

### unclear what you're asking

Exactly what it says on the tin: it is not clear from the question what information the asker needs in order to solve his problem.

Note that many "unclear" questions *are still questions* - and they may even be answerable, if the answerer is willing to make sufficient assumptions regarding the problem. Answerers who are [gamblers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127899/speculative-answers-discouraged-through-downvoting/127904#127904) or [psychics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39005/how-to-combat-psychic-answers) have a distinct advantage when it comes to answering these questions - and if such a question attracts a skilled answer from such a lucky / clairvoyant answerer, it may well be worth **editing it to reflect the answer** rather than closing it. The vast majority of these questions do not attract such answers, however.

#### Examples:

- [This question is unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993811/usb-should-mount-only-if-valid-password-is-given-by-the-user). In fact, it's not even clear that it's a programming question. It might be off-topic, it might be impossibly broad, or it might be trivial - who knows?
- [This question is also unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995644/writing-to-word-using-python) - it mentions errors without including them, and hints at the presence of other problems without describing them. In fact, it has a very helpful answer that spends a great deal of time politely pointing out how utterly out of his depth the answerer is. This question is unlikely to be clarified because the asker has no idea what he's actually doing, but if he did it would likely be too broad as well.

### too broad

Answers on Stack Overflow are limited to a paltry 30,000 characters. That's barely enough for a brief academic paper; a comprehensive tutorial on a subject of any size is unlikely to fit, and even a svelte book on any programming topic is *right out*.

In practice, very few answerers have the patience to write even that much. This is fine; there are other sites that cater to full-length articles. We're here to answer specific questions.

But some questions aren't specific. Some questions just lead to *more* questions. Others explicitly *contain* multiple, independent questions! A common motivation is an asker with a fairly basic understanding of a topic who wishes to leapfrog past the whole "study, trial and error" page and find that mythical Royal Road to programming. These are discouraged - rather someone ask multiple questions (or read the answers to existing ones), building their knowledge from the foundations up than require a personal tutor to walk them through the process.

#### Examples:

- [Implementing RDP in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030124/how-to-create-a-server-in-node-js-which-can-provide-remote-desktop-connection) is a pretty major undertaking. Particularly if he wants to implement the clients that way too, although it's unclear if he does.
- [Capturing video is a broad topic even if you're *not* still learning the basics of GUI design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027012/capture-button-property-vb-net).
- [Re-implementing Tor in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981293/making-a-proxy-server) could be an interesting weekend project, I guess. It's a bit beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow question though.

### primarily opinion-based

[You know what they say about opinions...](https://www.google.com/search?q=opinions%20are%20like) There are a bunch of questions that are either *designed* or *destined* to collect raw opinions, devoid of anything verifiable. Sometimes, these are a lot of fun; other times, they're fertile ground for flame-wars.

#### Examples

- [Nothing will make you well-rounded like COBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671135/in-general-what-programming-languages-should-someone-learn-to-be-well-rounded). Except maybe donuts.
- [Not only is this opinion-based, it's apparently intended SOLELY for fortune-tellers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758940/what-programming-tools-havent-been-written-yet). And yes, I did get my future ham.
- [I'm throwing this one in as an example of a personal advice question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028369/audio-processing-on-windows-phone) - although the bulk of it is just unclear, requesting advice on which platform you should develop for without any specific requirements crosses the line into opinion-territory.

### off topic

These are *supposed* to be self-explanatory - hence the recent removal of a couple of oft-misinterpreted ones; if it's helpful, I can provide examples for them too though. The newest off-topic reason is:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can't be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

...and it's aimed squarely at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions) sort of thing.

Comment: So what close reason would you give for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674439/) under the current scheme? Under the old scheme, I would have gone with "too localized" as it's unlikely to help anyone else (from the site's target audience). Under the previous scheme, it pretty clearly fell under "minimal understanding." Would it be "too broad" now, because we would need to fill in too many pieces for the OP? It's really not that many pieces though; here's the formula, here's how the code would look. Write in a close reason? Leave open? Something else?

Comment: Those are great examples, I sure hope you have some way of marking them to not be deleted in the future so they can keep being those examples.

Comment: "this one *was solved* in a manner unlikely to help future readers" kind of implies it's only relevant once an answer has been accepted, doesn't it? Maybe reword to something like "this one is unlikely to be useful to future readers?"

Comment: Thanks, Shog9 for your explanations, but I also have still problems like @TheCommunity. I review regularly the regex questions and there are so many, just asking for code, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291272/rename-file-in-mac-os-terminal-using-regex), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682123/search-and-replace-n-or-t-with-and-empty-space) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682721/reg-expression-to-retrieve-the-values-from-data). I think it is clear that they should be closed, but the reason???

Comment: @stema that second one is a great example, I want to close vote but am not sure what reason to give. It has two off-topic close votes, but we can't see what they are, so they were probably old "minimal understanding" votes. I wonder if it would be closed by now if "minimal understanding" were still here. If stuff like this should be closed, there should probably be a good boilerplate reason, so it's clear to everyone that it really should be closed.

Comment: @stema The second one would be "unclear what you're asking" (the comments even suggest some confusion - is the OP asking for help with their tool?  Why is it tagged regex then?).  The third one could also be "unclear what you're asking" because it's not very specific.  Not sure about the first one.  And if you think the OP didn't put enough effort into their questions, make sure to downvote them.  Like the tooltip says, downvotes are for questions that did not show any research effort, are unclear, or unuseful.

Comment: @stema Actually, I'm not sure the first one is really close-worthy.

Comment: @Troyen the second one seems pretty clear to me. "Here's what I want to do, here are the tools I'm using now." I would assume he just wants it to get done and doesn't care how, and shared all the information he had. A gedit answer or a sed answer would both probably satisfy him. In gedit, I'm almost positive escaping the backslash with another backslash would do the trick, but anyone with a *minimal understanding* of what they're doing would have tried that by now. "Unclear" seems like a stretch to me. If it should be closed, there should probably be a better (authoritative) reason.

Comment: @TheCommunity If you understand what's being asked, then it's not an unclear question (I just assumed it was because of the comments). Based on all the other discussions today, it sounds like it shouldn't be closed then.

Comment: Agreeing with @TheCommunity. I have some linguistic reservations about this close reason, too. Why did you decide on "solved" where _questions_ are concerned?

Comment: @TheCommunity: you're doing exactly what I tried to avoid - you're looking for questions that match a simple pattern instead of, upon finding a question and seeing a problem with it, looking for a close reason that describes that. Also, you're utterly missing the point of the typo reason even though I state it in the reason *and* link to a big discussion of it: they're blatantly obvious, you can put away your magnifying glass.

Comment: You have three different questions with (at least) three different issues, @stema: the first one is off-topic (belongs on either [apple.se] or [unix.se]), the second is missing a tag, and the third is unclear.

Comment: @Shog9, I'm not sure what you mean. Troyen linked a question, I found it via his link, I see problems with it (seems not useful to anyone except asker, very low quality, etc.), I want to close it, I'm looking for a close reason that describes it, I can't find one. I'm not *looking* for questions, I just happened to *find* one. The opposite of what you are saying is true, AFAICT.

Comment: As for the second part, I get the point of the typo reason. Trust me. That whole typo crusade stemmed from a question I posted in the first place, remember? I'm just saying that I think the wording could be confusing to someone else (probably an asker), not that it's confusing to me.

Comment: @Shog9 If you were talking about the question I mentioned in my first comment, I found that "organically" as well, some time back. I didn't have to go looking for it, it stood out in my mind as an example of a particularly bad question that the "minimal understanding" close reason seemed particularly fitting for. If I were to happen across another question like that now, I would be completely unsure of what to do with it. Do we *want* that question? If so, fine. If not, what do I close it as?

Comment: So what's the problem with the question you linked, @TheCommunity?

Comment: @Shog9, the same problem the close voters identified. Just because the problem can't be supported by the current language in the FAQ or the close reasons doesn't necessarily mean it's not actually a problem. If we could find a significant number of people who want that question here, then maybe I'm wrong and there's no problem in this case. If we can't, then it's probably a problem. IOW my plain answer would be something along the lines of "it's garbage and nobody wants it," but obviously that would need a huge amount of dressing up before its ready for general consumption as a close reason.

Comment: "It's crap." is a good start, @TheCommunity. Then you need to classify the problem: is this a question that can't or shouldn't be answered here? Find a close reason that fits. Is it just poorly-asked? Down-vote it.

Comment: In my opinion it's a question that shouldn't be answered because answering that question just invites infinite permutations of questions like that. How do I convert liters to gallons in Visual Basic? It's just going to drive people nuts. I can't find a close reason that fits that reasoning, as I said in the initial comment. I still think it should be closed, and I don't want to have to resort to [this kind of abuse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737165/) to close questions. Should I write in my "infinite permutations" close reason then?

Comment: By the way, I only answered the question linked in the last comment because I felt bad for the guy for getting such a phoned-in close reason. If there had been a more fitting close reason I probably would have CVd.

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737165/web-application-project-for-beginner) question falls into the "opinion-based" category, IMHO - but note that [programmers.se] has a specific off-topic reason addressing them (since so many people think personal advice questions are on-topic there). Anyway, if you think [the first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674439/how-to-convert-meter-to-miles) is off-topic because unit conversion formulas aren't programming, then that's a perfect time to select "off-topic->other"...

Comment: I thought that one was opinion based too until I actually sat down and wrote an answer; after that I didn't feel like I had written anything that was just my opinion. If it had been getting opinion-based CVs, though, I imagine I probably would have piled on. I guess my issue with the first question isn't so much that unit conversion isn't programming, but that it really has nothing to do with the language in question. IOW looking up the formula and a *minimal understanding* of the language should have been enough.

Comment: The nature of an opinion-based question is that many people may feel they have a good answer to it, with little in the way of support for their assertions, @the. That said, if you feel that question can be answered objectively you *may* want to vote to reopen it...

Answer (score 1):

The cheat sheet is the entry in [the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) that discusses closed questions.

What specifically in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions is lacking?

<sub>(i.e. Rather than ask if we need a more detailed list, why not propose specific wording for one close reason - the one that is most lacking/misused/underused and build a case for why the current documentation is lacking?)</sub>

Comment: You see a bug perhaps, I see a feature.

Comment: Really? It lacks brevity? Three lines or fewer per reason is seriously not brief enough?

Comment: @JonathanGarber what am I supposed to be looking at? I follow that link and see a page of more links.

Comment: "[What does it mean if a question is closed or on hold?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)".

Comment: @JonathanGarber that looks more like a reference for askers than for closers to me.

Comment: That page is lacking details.  For instance, I learned from the [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding/215546#comment696378_215546) on another thread that a question that just lists a set of non-trivial requirements and asks how to build it, with no example code, should be closed as "too broad".  Is that right?  I don't see how I could derive that from the text in the FAQ.  In short: The FAQ needs more detail to help us closers know when to use the various close reasons, and when not to.....

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with having a separate resource for closers.

Comment: In my opinion, there should be information on when to close on what grounds here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation - as this section is apparently concerned with "moderation".