# Help in picking correct close reasons with more info in the vote-to-close dialog

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I try to do my part getting the close-votes queue down. Recently I've noticed the close reasons changing *a lot*. This is probably for the better, but it's confusing me. For someone not *too* active on Meta, I have no real clue what the new consensus is.

Note that I'm not asking about an [explanation of the changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow). Instead, I'd like to see some direct link(s) or an inline explanation in the close-vote dialog that helps me answer these (kind of) questions:

1. I "know/feel" this question should be closed, but what reason should I pick?
2. What is the more verbose explanation of a certain close-reason? When should it be chosen?

I know the close reasons themselves should be fairly explanatory, and they are, but nonetheless I sometimes get confused and would like to know more to make sure I choose the correct reasons (or even close more/less, if that consensus changed).

PS. All this is assuming there *is* a more detailed explanation (FAQ) of the most current close-reasons. If there isn't ([I](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=close%20reasons%20explanation) [couldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=close%20reasons%20explanation%20votes:20%20is:q) [find it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BFAQ%5D%20close%20reasons%20is:q)) that may be a problem in itself. What probably comes close to (or even *is*) the thing I'm looking for was mentioned in the comments: the "[close reasons cheat sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215587/close-reasons-cheat-sheet)".

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216192/209637).

Comment: There is a small group of people that are [having a weekly event in this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to learn and exchange ideas when handling the close voting queue.  It might help to have a second reviewer at hand to discuss the corner cases.